# What is conversation in jboss seam?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, seam2

I am new to seam framework and have been using it since few weeks now. I came across some tags related to seam conversation. But I did not understand what conversation means and when to use it?

Can anybody give me some details about this with an example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Conversation is a intermediate context between Request and Session. It is not only related to a SGBD session as `glmlima` said. You can use a conversation always that you want to maintain the state os your beans through many requests and pages (like when you wnat to buy a ticket to a show) and dont want to keep it in your session.

A conversation lasts as long as you want to use it and you can have as many conversations as you want in your session.

I hope it helps to understand conversational context.

Answer (score 0):

Which Seam Framework version are you using? In short, persistence contexts scoped to the conversation allows you to program optimistic transactions that span multiple requests to the server without the need to use the merge() operation , without the need to re-load data at the beginning of each request, and without the need to wrestle with the LazyInitializationException or NonUniqueObjectException (Seam Docs).

If you want to know the basic concepts about conversation, I suggest reading this [Seam Conversation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.1GA/reference/en/html/conversations.html).

If you are using the Seam 3, it has aggregate JavaEE6 new features, like CDI.

Comment: The link you mentioned talks about seam conversational model. But I want to understand what conversation means and when it is used.

Comment: @Newbie you can understand a conversation as the interval which the persistence provider maintain its session with SGBD opened. So, with a conversation, you avoid exceptions like LazyInicialization, Detached, and so on. For more information, I suggest https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView.